# Como corregir un error al momento de validar una imagen en C#

Tags: c#

Que tal amigos tengo un pequeño detalle, estoy queriendo validar campos vacíos en un formulario, ya tengo el condicional de cada campo, el detalle es que al momento de ejecutar el programa sin llenar ninguna dato doy clic en botón guardar me da una excepción en una variable que tengo como imagen con el nombre de picturefoto.

```
private void btnguardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string nombreChofer = textnombre.Text;
    string tipoVehiculo = cbxtipovehiculo.Text.ToString();
    string placas = textplaca.Text;
    string lugarOrigen = textlugarorigen.Text;
    string fecha = datefecha.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    string contenido = string.Empty;
    if (radiocargada.Checked == true)
    {
        contenido = "Caja cargada";
    }
    if (radiodescargada.Checked == true)
    {
        contenido = "Caja descargada";
    }
    string observaciones = richTextobservacion.Text;
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    picturefoto.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    byte[] aByte = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Captura de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese error te da pq el picturebox no tiene ninguna imagen